# Ionic: package.json missing start script

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

My `package.json` doesn't have a start script, so npm start will not work.

My package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
    "serve:before": "watch",
    "emulate:before": "build",
    "deploy:before": "build",
    "build:before": "build",
    "run:before": "build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.0",
    "es6-promise": "3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-native": "^2.2.14",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng2-cordova-oauth": "0.0.6",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.1.5"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "third-party-auth-ionic2-tutorial: An Ionic project"
}
```

What should the start script contain?

Comment: Please help me to come out this error

Comment: You do have a missing script. In fact, it seems you're missing a whole *question*. All I see is some gibberish JSON that tells me nothing about your problem. Please describe exactly what you are stuck on, with expected behaviour, exhibited erroneous behaviour, and what you tried to do to get from the former to the latter.

Comment: What's the question here

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found, Ionic projects do not use a start script in the package.json, so `npm start` is not needed.

use `ionic start` to create a new project and `ionic serve` to run the project during development as described in the [Getting Started Guide](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started).

There are other commands to build, deploy and package your project when needed, make sure to check the ionic documentation for how to do these the 'Ionic way'

Answer (score 0):

run cmd

***ionic integrations enable cordova --add***

update config.xml file and package.json file

for build purpose